# How to created template through java code in docusign by REST API?

Tags: api, rest, docusignapi

I wants to create template and generate template ID through Rest API call and send the documents with template to Docusign.
How to created template through java code in docusign.

Comment: Could use some clarifications. 1) Are you looking to create a DocuSign template using the API? Or are you looking to create an envelope by specifying a previously created/defined template?   2) You can create envelopes in a number of ways: passing the PDF bytes inline the API call OR specifying a pre-existing templateID OR a mix of PDF's and templates.

Comment: No, I want to send PDF with envelop.

Comment: The java samples available at https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/request-signatures demonstrate how to create and send an envelope by passing in the PDF bytes and specifying the signature tab location on the document using x/y coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a Template to send a PDF for signature.  A DocuSign Template is a design-time object you can create in your account that is used to streamline the sending process when you send the same or similar documents frequently.

However, if you do not know the document ahead of time or you want to let the user select a document in real-time then Templates won't work, you can just send a signature request from a local PDF or document in that case.

The **[Request Signature on Document](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/request-signatures)** Quickstart in the DocuSign Developer Center shows you how to accomplish this in numerous languages (including `Java`) so I recommend you take a look.